# How to subtract sheets in Excel

Tags: excel

I have two huge sets of data in excel sheets with just one column. One has a master data set and the other is a set of data which has a few data in common with the master data. How do you subtract both the data. Subtract as in I want to retain the values of master data set without anything in common with the data in the other data sheet.

Answer (score 1):

On your Master Data sheet (`Sheet1`), you can use a formula in Column `B` to lookup to the other set of data (`Sheet2`). In `Sheet1!B1` enter:

```
=IF(COUNTIF(Sheet2!A:A, Sheet1!A1)>0, 1,0)
```

Copy this formula down and you will get a 1 next to every line that has a match in Sheet2. You can this sort by this column and pull out items with a 0.

**How it works**: 
`COUNTIF()` takes two parameters. The first is the range we are searching, the second is the value that we are looking for in the range. `COUNTIF` returns the number of times that value is found in the range.

The `IF` statement then tests the results of the `COUNTIF` to see if it is greater than 0. Which means we've found at least one hit in the second sheet for that value. If it's greater than 0 it puts a `1` in that cell. If it's not then it get's a `0`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I tried using the VLOOKUP function by running it for the whole data using Ctrl + Enter but it returned #REF!. What error is that ?

Comment: #REF means that you have referred to a range incorrectly. The CTE is probably balking because vlookup is already sort of an Array formula as-is.

Comment: How do I copy the formula down to every row in B ? It says the size doesnt match

Comment: Copy B1, then highlight B2:B<whatever> and paste

Comment: No prob. I've been there many times myself. Don't even get me started on copying over merged cells. Excel is a strange place sometimes.

Comment: Yeah. I was completely lost working on that huge a data.

Comment: Can you explain how that function works ?

Comment: i have seen that countif can take two arguments generally. but how do those 4 work ?

Comment: No prob. I've added an explanation anyway. I usually put those in when I suggest a formula that is nested like that. I missed it on this answer so it was a good add.

Comment: would it be easier to work on such big data in R ? Or is excel a better option ?

Comment: The data is around two lakh entries in each sheet.

Comment: Really the ability to get a set of records back where one table doesn't match another is the perfect use case for a database. Access would be a good option here. A query like `SELECT * FROM [Sheet1] LEFT OUTER JOIN [Sheet2] ON [Sheet1].[Field1] = [Sheet2].[Field1] WHERE [Sheet2].[Field1] IS NULL` would return your answer very quickly even on a very very large data set.

Comment: Also, 2 lakh is huge for excel, so it will take a while to do this work, but for a database, a couple hundred thousand records is a very manageable amount of data.